# My Android Samsung won't switch on or charge after it got wet

Tags: privacy

My phone got wet. So I left it in rice and blow dried it with a hair blower. I've left it on charge for a day and it did not switch on or showed that it's charging. I left the battery outside for quite a while but still seems not to work.

PLEASE I WOULD APPRECIATE SOME HELP

Comment: http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-fix-water-damaged-phone-647461/

Answer (score 1):

> Now, if the phone doesn’t work, it’s time to accept defeat and take it to a professional and see if it can be salvaged. You can also claim insurance if you have it. Not to sound like a doctor, but after this point we have really done everything we could. Sometimes you just have to let the phone go.

http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-fix-water-damaged-phone-647461/